# Machine Learning: Why is Linear Regression Cost Function First Decreasing then Increasing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have trained a multivariate linear regression model on data available in this .csv file: https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data/downloads/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data.zip/3
I trained it (gradient descent) as such:

```
alpha = 0.1
rd: int = 0
while epoch <= 4000:
    rd = 0
    epoch += 1
    print("Epoch: "+str(epoch))
    while rd <= 48894:
        expected_y: float = x1a[rd] * w[0]
        expected_y += x1b[rd] * w[1]
        expected_y += x1c[rd] * w[2]
        expected_y += x1d[rd] * w[3]
        expected_y += x1e[rd] * w[4]
        expected_y += x2p[rd] * w[5]
        expected_y += x2e[rd] * w[6]
        expected_y += x2s[rd] * w[7]
        expected_y += x3[rd] * w[8]
        expected_y += x4[rd] * w[9]
        expected_y += x5[rd] * w[10]
        expected_y += x6[rd] * w[11]
        expected_y += x7[rd] * w[12] + b
        actual_y: float = y[rd]
        disparity: float = expected_y - actual_y
        b -= 2 * alpha * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[0] -= 2 * alpha * x1a[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[1] -= 2 * alpha * x1b[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[2] -= 2 * alpha * x1c[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[3] -= 2 * alpha * x1d[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[4] -= 2 * alpha * x1e[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[5] -= 2 * alpha * x2p[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[6] -= 2 * alpha * x2e[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[7] -= 2 * alpha * x2s[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[8] -= 2 * alpha * x3[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[9] -= 2 * alpha * x4[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[10] -= 2 * alpha * x5[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[11] -= 2 * alpha * x6[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        w[12] -= 2 * alpha * x7[rd] * disparity * (1 / 48894)
        rd += 1
    if epoch % 2 == 0:
        te = 0
        mean_squared_error: float = 0
        while te <= 48894:
            expected_y = x1a[te] * w[0] + x1b[te] * w[1] + x1c[te] * w[2] + x1d[te] * w[3] + x1e[te] * w[4]
            expected_y += x2p[te] * w[5]
            expected_y += x2e[te] * w[6] + x2s[te] * w[7] + x3[te] * w[8] + x4[te] * w[9] + x5[te] * w[10]
            expected_y += x6[te] * w[11]
            expected_y += x7[te] * w[12] + b
            actual_y = y[te]
            disparity = expected_y - actual_y
            mean_squared_error += disparity ** 2
            te += 1
        print("\t\tEpoch: " + str(epoch) + "\n\t\tMSE:" + str(mean_squared_error))
```

The loss/cost function (mean squared error) keeps decreasing as expected till the 712th epoch, then starts increasing (albeit slowly). What does this mean, and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: This happens normally when your alpha is too large. Try some smaller values for alpha.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you trying to use a large learning rate (`alpha`) and it means that your model takes a huge step in gradient descent to find a global minimum and may your cost function after a number of iterations decreasing it will increase and overshooting global minimum and fail to converge or even diverge. so in your case probably taking small steps ( decreasing learning rate `alpha` ) will guarantee that gradient descent will converge to global optima.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your goal is to minimize the cost function theta. If you use gradient descent you need to make sure your learning rate alpha is not large. Your hypothesis should end up in global minimum not at local optimum. Gradient descent should take small steps in finding the global minimum which best fits the training model.